# Parameterized Groovy JUnit test-cases in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, groovy, junit, parameterized-tests, groovy-eclipse

I'm having trouble running a `Parameterized` Groovy JUnit test-case in Eclipse (see below for test code and environment details).

**Symptoms**

- Right-clicking on the class in Package Explorer and doing **Run As -> JUnit Test Case** just brings up a dialog claiming "No JUnit tests found".
- Right-clicking on the project and doing **Run As -> JUnit Test Case** runs all test-cases *except* the parameterized Groovy one.

**Things I've tried**

1. Ensuring a "normal" Groovy JUnit test-case runs.  *This works.*
2. Ensuring a parameterized Java test-case runs.  *This works.*
3. Manually creating a JUnit run configuration for this test-case.  *This works.*

**So**

So I have an inconvenient workaround (3).  But this isn't scalable, as this test-case still won't be included when I run all test-cases in the project.

Any ideas how I can get Eclipse/Groovy plugin/JUnit to automatically recognise my test-case?

---

<sub>**Test-case code**</sub>

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters

@RunWith(Parameterized)
public class TestParams {
    final int a

    public TestParams(int a) { this.a = a }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        def cases = new Object[2][1]
        cases[0][0] = 3
        cases[1][0] = 4
        Arrays.asList(cases)
    }

    @Test public void test() { println "a = $a" }
}
```

**Environment**

- Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 (OSX)
- Groovy-Eclipse 2.8.0
- JUnit 4.10.0

Comment: Hmmm...I am running in Kepler with Groovy-Eclipse 2.8.0 and the 2.1.5 compiler.  This is working for me.  Do you have any errors in your error log?  Does content assist/navigation work inside of your class?

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg: Content-assist seems to work ok, and no errors reported (as I say, this runs fine with an explicit run configuration).  I am yet to explore Kepler (the IDE crashes immediately on my OSX).  However, my general experience of the Groovy-Eclipse plugin (so far) is that it's **extremely** temperamental and buggy, so maybe I'm just unlucky here!

Answer (score 1):

this code works on my juno eclipse, junit 4.10 and groovy 2.0.6. i started with your code, but had to fool around with the imports as some of the annotations were red. i also had to add the .class to parameterized.

```
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters
@RunWith(Parameterized.class) public class TestParams {
    final int a

    public TestParams(int a) { this.a = a }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        def cases = new Object[2][1]
        cases[0][0] = 3
        cases[1][0] = 4
        Arrays.asList(cases)
    }

    @Test public void test() { println "a = $a" }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work for me either, although I haven't tried rolling back to Groovy-Eclipse 2.0.6 (I'll try that tomorrow...)  So if you change `Parameterized.class` back to `Parameterized`, it no longer works for you?

Comment: oop, if i remove the .class, it still works. sorry about the confusion.